# Element API: Is it possible to ignore/skip an Entry?

Tags: craft3, plugin-elementapi

I would like to exclude some of my entries, via my own validation inside the `Transformer`, from the api output.

Is there a possibility to move on to the next Entry without outputing anything? Right now im just returning an empty array, but i think it would be cleaner to return nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you modify the criteria to exclude that entry ?

```
id => "not X"
```

Comment: I want to make the desicion after the criteria's, inside the transformer. Lets say get all Entries from a type but only output those that pass my own validation.